# White noise does not contradicts Wide Sense Stationarity?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity, signal-processing

White noise is usually defined as a **wide sense stationary (WSS)** process $N=\{N_t|t\in T\}$ (for $T$ a time index set), that has a constant power spectral density, say $S_{NN}(f)=\sigma^2$.  Since the correlation function $R_{NN}(t)=\mathcal{F}[S_{NN}(f)]$, we have also that $R_{NN}(t)=\sigma^2\delta(t)$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.  The thing is that $\mathbb{E}\{|N_t|^2\}=R_{NN}(0)=\sigma^2\delta(0)$. Indeed, if we assume that $N$ is ergodic we have that power is also the variance of the process:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}(N)
&= R_{NN}(0) - \mu_N(t) \\[14pt]
&= R_{NN}(0) \\[6pt]
&= \lim_{\tau\to\infty} \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbb{E}\{|\hat{N}^\tau(f)|^2\}}{2\tau} \ df, \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

where $\hat{N}^\tau$ is the Fourier transform of windowing of $N$ on a interval of lenght $2\tau$. So, what I do not understand is how $N$ can be WSS if it has an infinite power and variance, because:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sigma^2 \ df=\infty.$$

As you can see, I am requiring a process to have finite second moment for being WSS. Also, I have that this white noise has identical distribution with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$.

I feel that I have a big misconception, but I do not know where the problem is. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the "second moment" of a process?  That might get to the heart of the matter.

Comment: Thanks! I mean $\mathbb{E}\{|X_t|^2\}$ for every $t$ by the second moment

Comment: What is PSD?  ..

Comment: I have edited it yet

Comment: "Infinite power and variance" refer to the integrals you have written, but the expression in your comment is the variance of the random value *at a single time*--no integration over time is involved.  How, then, can those quantities even be compared??

Comment: I understand what you say, but my confusion lies on the fact that for a WN, $\sigma^2\delta(0)=R_{NN}(0)=\mathbb{E}\{N_t^2\}$. And by hypothesis, $\sigma^2=\mathbb{E}\{N_t^2\}<\infty$. So, I see a contradiction when we have $\sigma^2=\sigma^2\delta(0)$.

Comment: By definition, $\delta(0)=1,$ so you seem to asking why $\sigma^2 = \sigma^2(1).$

Comment: [Also asked on dsp.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/80662/235) where it is a more natural fit, and where a similar question has already been asked and answered.

Comment: @whuber $\delta(0) = 1$? The OP refers to the Dirac delta, not to the discrete delta.

Comment: @Massimo Although they *call* it that, it is functioning as the indicator of $0.$

Comment: @whuber Are you confusing with the discrete delta? The OP is referring to a _continuous_ white noise process (see my answer below). Indeed in the case of a _discrete_ white noise process, that delta is the discrete delta such that $\delta(0) =1$.

Comment: @Massimo I understand the distinction and am not confusing them.  It is quite possible I have misinterpreted the notation (which is unexplained), but I have understood the notation "$R_{NN}(0)$" to mean the common variance of each random variable $N_t;$ that is, $R_{NN}(0)=E[N_t N_{t-0}]-\mu_N(t)\mu_N(t-0).$

Comment: @whuber Yes, you understood that notation correctly, and for a continuous white noise that variance is infinite or, rather, not defined.

Comment: @Massimo Thank you.  I see you are taking the approach sketched at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#Continuous-time_white_noise, in which case $\delta$ must be the Dirac distribution and not an indicator function.

Comment: @whuber Yes, exactly. That approach is common in the engineering literature, less so in the mathematical literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, strictly speaking a *continuous* white noise is *not* a WSS process because its variance is not finite, and is actually not even defined (the *discrete* white noise is instead WSS).

There are two alternative ways to solve this issue: the first is to consider that in any real system excited by white noise the bandwidth is finite, such that the variance of the filtered process is finite; the second is to enlarge the class of stochastic processes in the same way we enlarge the class of functions to include generalized functions (distributions) like the delta "function".

The former approach is common in the engineering literature, where white noise is typically used to model thermal noise in electronic and communication circuits, which indeed have a finite bandwidth. This approach, which is a bit of handwaving, is the simplest but not mathematically sound.

The latter approach can be implemented by considering stochastic processes as linear functionals associating a random variable to any function in a certain class of test functions. The correlation function for these generalized processes is defined as a bilinear functional on the class of test functions, and it has a finite value for all test functions in the case of continuous white noise. The details of this approach can be found in section 24.1 of the following book:

A. M. Yaglom, *Correlation theory of stationary and random functions*, vol. I; *Basic results*, Springer
Series in Statistics, Springer-Verlag, 1987.

Comment: Thank you so much Massimo Ortolano. Also, I was thinking, is not a bit rare that if we define a white noise (in the continuous sense) as an indexed list of independent and identically distributed r.a. with variance $\sigma^2$, the correlation ends up giving $Var(N_t)=\sigma^2\delta(0)\neq\sigma^2$ ?